# Blog Site Categories WebPart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a blog subsite and have created a custom page layout where i would like to add the Categories and Archives web parts that comes with the OOTB `default.aspx` page.

I can add the Archives webpart its available under Blog categories (via Insert Webpart option) but how do i add the Categories web part. I can also see that the links in the Categories are redirected to `Category.aspx` page with URL `/category.aspx?CategoryId=3`

How can i recreate this?

Reference Image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dig into the existing Category Web Part code and found that `XsltListViewWebPart` was used to create that. So you can create it using `XsltListViewWebPart`

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" ViewFlag="" ViewSelectorFetchAsync="False" InplaceSearchEnabled="True" ServerRender="False" ClientRender="True" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" IsClientRender="False" GhostedXslLink="blog.xsl" NoDefaultStyle="" ViewGuid="{001EB8C0-940B-4CFD-91CC-0E5B969F8A0F}" EnableOriginalValue="False" ViewContentTypeId="" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{3A0A4709-9296-4A81-AF0D-23F20367C2BC}" ListId="3a0a4709-9296-4a81-af0d-23f20367c2bc" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" Title="Categories" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="Use the Categories list to define the categories available for posts." IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="BlogNavigator" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" TitleUrl="/myblog/Lists/Categories" DetailLink="/myblog/Lists/Categories" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="False" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_001eb8c0_940b_4cfd_91cc_0e5b969f8a0f" ChromeType="None" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{001EB8C0-940B-4CFD-91CC-0E5B969F8A0F}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="Fldtypes_mswhTitle.xsl;fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
   <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
      <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
      <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
      <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
      <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(core,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)" />
   </ParameterBindings>
   <DataFields></DataFields>
   <XmlDefinition>
      <View Name="{001EB8C0-940B-4CFD-91CC-0E5B969F8A0F}" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="/myblog/default.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="0" ContentTypeID="0x" >
         <Query>
            <OrderBy>
               <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="TRUE"/>
            </OrderBy>
         </Query>
         <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
         </ViewFields>
         <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
         <JSLink>sp.ui.blogs.js</JSLink>
         <XslLink>blog.xsl</XslLink>
         <Toolbar Type="None"/>
      </View>
   </XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

**Another solution:** You can modify one of your view using **CSR** and the add this view as web part.

[image]

I have modified **My Categories** View using **CSR** to get your desired link(`/category.aspx?CategoryId=3`).

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      // OnPreRender: function(ctx) { },

      Templates: {

      //     View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Header: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Body: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Group: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Item: function(ctx) { return ""; },
           Fields: {
               "Title": {
                   View: function(ctx) { 
                     var categoryLink = "/myblog/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?CategoryId=" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
                     var titleWithLink = String.format("<a href='{0}' target='_blank' id='blgcat3' class='ms-core-listMenu-item ms-blog-quickLinksEntry'>{1}</a>",categoryLink,ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                     return titleWithLink; 
                   },
      //             EditForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //             DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //             NewForm: function(ctx) { return ""; }
              }
           },
      //     Footer: function(ctx) { return ""; }

      },

      // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },

      ListTemplateType: 303

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/categoryWebPartView.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

After applying this JsLink in my view I am getting following output

[image]

Comment: I am well aware of adding categories webpart, please read the second part of the question. I require the links point to Categories.aspx page with CategoryId as query id.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: see my update now